# helper function not resolving correctly

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Hi I am having a helm chart named **test-service**. I have a helper chart named **helm-common-templates**. my chart has dependency on the **helm-common-templates**. it has a function named "helm-common-templates.certificate-enabled" defined in it . The following is the function.

```
{{- define "helm-common-templates.certificate-enabled" -}}
{{- $val := "false" }}
{{- if .Values.global -}}
{{- if .Values.global.pms -}}
{{- if .Values.global.pms.logstash -}}
{{- if .Values.global.pms.logstash.tls -}}
{{- if .Values.global.pms.logstash.tls.enabled -}}
{{- $val := "true" }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{ $val }}
{{- end -}}
```

The function basically return true if the property `global.pms.logstash.tls.enabled` is set to true else return false. In my main chart I am calling the function in a file named certificate.yaml

The following is the content of the file certificate.yaml

```
{{ if eq (include "helm-common-templates.certificate-enabled" .) "true" }}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: ls-secret
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "post-delete"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation, hook-succeeded"
data:

---
{{end}}
```

if i give dry run i get the following output

```
helm upgrade --install --debug  test --namespace bcc --wait --timeout "10m0s"  --set global.pms.logstash.tls.enabled=true  . --dry-run
```

output

```
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release test
Release "test" does not exist. Installing it now.
install.go:192: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:209: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/prabpras/filebeat-testing/test-service

NAME: test
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Nov  1 14:50:28 2023
NAMESPACE: bcc
STATUS: pending-install
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
global:
  pms:
    logstash:
      tls:
        enabled: true

COMPUTED VALUES:
global:
  kubernetes: {}
  pms:
    logstash:
      tls:
        enabled: true
  tls:
    enabled: true
    truststore: {}
  tracing:
    type: NoOp
helm-common-templates:
  global:
    kubernetes: {}
    pms:
      logstash:
        tls:
          enabled: true
    tls:
      enabled: true
      truststore: {}
    tracing:
      type: NoOp
HOOKS:
MANIFEST:
```

I could see that the secret resource in the certificate.yaml is not rendered in the dry run output. basically the function `helm-common-templates.certificate-enabled` always returns false.

I am also attaching the directory structure of my chart

```
test-service]$ tree
.
|-- Chart.yaml
|-- charts
|   `-- helm-common-templates
|       |-- Chart.yaml
|       `-- templates
|           `-- _helpers.tpl
|-- requirements.yaml
|-- templates
|   |-- NOTES.txt
|   |-- _helpers.tpl
|   `-- certificate.yaml
`-- values.yaml
```

appreciate any help.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem you're running into are that variable assignments `$var := val` are block-scoped in the Go template language.  At an absolute minimum, a template like

```
{{ $var := "foo" }}
{{ if true }}
{{ $var := "bar" }}
{{ end }}
{{ $var }}
```

will always print out `foo`: the assignment inside the `if` statement creates a new variable.

The template language allows reassigning an existing variable.  This is similar to the distinction between `:=` that creates a new variable and `=` that assigns an existing one in Go.  If you remove the colon at the inside of the conditional it will reassign the variable

```
{{- $val := "false" }}
{{- if ... -}}
{{- $val = "true" }}
{{/*-    ^ no colon here -*/}}
{{- end -}}
{{ $val }}
```

(This was [added in Go 1.11](https://go.dev/doc/go1.11), 5 years ago as of this writing, and it should work in current versions of Helm.)

For the very-deeply-nested lookup, you might find it more convenient to use the [`dig`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dig) template function, which will also tolerate missing layers of the values file (what happens if `.Values.global.pms` just doesn't exist?).  That could look like

```
{{- define "helm-common-templates.certificate-enabled" -}}
{{- dig "global" "pms" "logstash" "tls" "enabled" "false" .Values -}}
{{- end }}
```

where `"false"` at the end is the default value if the value isn't present or is false (also zero, empty string, empty list, empty map).

Answer (score 0):

we got is solved. rewritted the helper function to use printf

```
{{- define "certificate-enabled" -}}
{{- if ((((.Values.global).pms).logstash).tls).enabled -}}
{{- printf "true" }}
{{- else -}}
{{- printf "false" }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```